# a query that tells the number of submits for each location along with the location's name

Tags: mysql

My users submit information for locations.  I'm trying to write a query that will tell me the number of submits they've done for each location along with that location's name.

This query seems to be a start in the right direction.  It returns the id for each location that the user has submitted information.

```
SELECT reports.location_id
FROM reports
WHERE reports.user_id =104
ORDER BY reports.locations_id
```

An example of the return from this query is:

```
locations_id
99
99
99
112
115
115
```

For my final html output; however, I would like to show something more along the lines of this:

```
   location_name  number_of_submits
    name_1        3
    name_2        1
    name_3        2
```

Is there a mysql query I could use to get this?  Or would I need to use php to iterate through my query's results (i.e. recognize 99 was returned 3 times and fetch 99's name from the locations table, then recognize 112 was returned once and fetch its name, and so on).

Thank you...

Comment: Is the `location_name` a column on your `reports` table? Is it unique? If not, what should happen when two locations have different IDs but the same name?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  The location_name is in a different table.  That's part of what makes this difficult for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP BY / COUNT:

```
SELECT
    location_name,
    COUNT(*) AS number_of_submits
FROM reports
JOIN markers ON markers.id = reports.location_id
WHERE reports.user_id = 104
GROUP BY reports.location_id
```

Comment: This is very cool.  I tried it with using "location_id" instead of "location_name" because "location_name" isn't in the reports table.  It works great, but it obviously returns the id instead of the name with my edit.  Any chance you could help me tweak it to fetch the name from a table called 'markers'?

Comment: Thanks! This works, I just had to change 'user_id' to 'reports.user_id' because user_id is in both tables.